# PHP variable to javascript, two pages .php and .html

Tags: javascript, php

Develop a PHP page where I get data from an Oracle database, then send them to a javascript page and there , make certain processes, but not how. The only thing I did is printed the value of php variable to assign to a javascript variable, but currently I take it as text. Can I have support please!!!. Greetings.

```
<script src="pagos_no_aplicados_0.php" ></script>

var q5="<?php echo$elemento5;?>"; //only printt to text
```

Comment: Um, what? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Encode your PHP variable into JSON and make its way into the page's javascript:

```html
<?php
$phpVariable = array(
    'what' => 'Hello!'
);
;?>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dataFromPhp = <?php echo json_encode($phpVariable) ;?>;
alert(dataFromPhp.what);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but only print text:   in php = $fila = oci_fetch_array($PAGOS, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
    foreach ($fila as $elemento) 
    echo $elemento;
    $elemento= array('q1' => , $elemento);   and javascritp= <script src="pagos_no_apliacados_0.php" ></script>
     var q1="<?php echo json_encode($elemento); ?>";

Comment: there are two programms one conexion.php and two printt.html